# Cant import package and its functions - Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have installed a particular Python package, lmoments (https://pypi.org/project/lmoments/), but cant seem to use its functions when i import. 
However, if i copy the contained files to my directory then it works fine. Any clue why this is and how to solve it ?

I am on the macOS HIgh Sierra and installed the package through the terminal (pip install lmoments==0.2.2), and the installed folder in my libraries looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHsFT.png). In my limited understanding, *import lmoments* should open the [***init*** file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXNQH.png) which then imports all the other files. But instead it throws an error to the effect that the lmomenst module has no such function.

Comment: How did you install it? What does your code look like? What operating system?

Comment: Could you provide your code example?

Comment: Made edits. Thanks!

Comment: If you want easy python package installation, I can recommend to use Anaconda instead. You will have far less trouble then.

Comment: Do you mean conda install lmoments ? I tried that. But the problem still seems to be that the .py file and the containing folder have the same names. Is that possible ?